# Fetching JSON in Google Sheets (ImportJSONAdvanced not defined?)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, import, authentication

Currently working on fetching data from an API with Basic Authentication. Through this script: https://gist.github.com/anemitz/8cc6ef6c41ea4cefe51a13fbd6d8676a

```
function ImportJSONBasicAuthentication(url, query, parseOptions, username, password) {

  var fetchOptions = {
    "headers" : {
       "Authorization" : 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password)
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
}
```

Inserted the script to Google Script Editor (in Google Sheets) but when running the script the same error keeps coming back:

> 'ReferenceError: "ImportJSONAdvanced" is not defined. (line 10)'

In the actual sheet I am calling

> =ImportJSONBasicAuthentication("url", "query", "noInherit, noTruncate", "api_key", )

Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask]. Also add more details to the question, like how did you found that code snippet and why do you think that it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The function `ImportJSONBasicAuthentication` is basically just a wrapper function for `ImportJSONAdvanced` but changes some options before calling it (the line with `var fetchOptions` initiliaztion call sets up options accordingly). You'd need to include the function `ImportJSONAdvanced` and any functions it might also call (dependancies).

Notice the return value of the `ImportJSONBasicAuthentication` is just a call to `ImportJSONAdvanced`. Hence, your error that mentions `ImportJSONAdvanced`.

So you're just overlooking it's dependent on another function, namely `ImportJSONAdvanced`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's relying on the the JSON import library by Chris Keller, [found here](https://gist.github.com/chrislkeller/5719258).

As its description says,

> To use go to Tools --> Script Editor and add the script and save.

This means the entire script, not just one function from it.